# Need another way to compare strings node.js if else statement crashes the call stack

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am having a problem I have a huge list of strings I need to compare and if a match is found it sets a variable. I am trying to do this in node.js express app. When I try to run this as an if/else statement in a foreach loop the call stack is exceeded. I need another way to compare strings and set a variable if a match is found. The data I am comparing has 8000 rows. and at times we will be running this against 200 strings. is this possible?

```
    <%
processFiles = function(files){
if (files==="000001.pdf") {sDesc = "Title Page"}
  else if (files==="00001.pdf") {sDesc = "Project Title Page"}
        else if (files==="00350.pdf") {sDesc = "Project Financial Information"}
  else if (files==="00360.pdf") {sDesc = "Permit Application"}
  else if (files==="00400.pdf") {sDesc = "Bid Forms and Supplements"}
  else if (files==="00410.pdf") {sDesc = "Bid Forms"}
  else if (files==="004213.pdf") {sDesc = "Proposal Form"}
  else if (files==="00430.pdf") {sDesc = "Bid Form Supplements"}
  else if (files==="01455.pdf") {sDesc = "Mechanical Equipment Testing Adjusting Balancing"}
  else if (files==="01458.pdf") {sDesc = "Testing Laboratory Services"}
  else if (files==="014600.pdf") {sDesc = "Quality Procedures"}
  else if (files==="014620.pdf") {sDesc = "Testing Agency Services"}
  else if (files==="01465.pdf") {sDesc = "Equipment Testing and Startup"}
  else if (files==="01500.pdf") {sDesc = "Temporary Facilities and Controls"}
  else if (files==="015000.pdf") {sDesc = "Temporary Facilities and Controls"}
  else if (files==="01510.pdf") {sDesc = "Temporary Utilities"}
  else if (files==="015100.pdf") {sDesc = "Temporary Utilities"}
  else if (files==="01520.pdf") {sDesc = "Construction Facilities"}
  else if (files==="015200.pdf") {sDesc = "Field Offices and Sheds"}
  else if (files==="015240.pdf") {sDesc = "Construction Waste Management"}
  else if (files==="01530.pdf") {sDesc = "Temporary Construction"}
  else if (files==="01540.pdf") {sDesc = "Construction Aids"}
  else if (files==="015400.pdf") {sDesc = "Construction Aides"}
  else if (files==="015420.pdf") {sDesc = "USe of Government Crane and Elevator"}
  else if (files==="01550.pdf") {sDesc = "Vehicular Access and Parking"}
  else if (files==="015500.pdf") {sDesc = "Vehicular Access and Parking"}
  else if (files==="015520.pdf") {sDesc = "Traffic Control"}
  else if (files==="01560.pdf") {sDesc = "Temporary Barriers and Enclosures"}
  else if (files==="015600.pdf") {sDesc = "Barriers"}
  else if (files==="015610.pdf") {sDesc = "Protection of Existing Installations"}
  else if (files==="015632.pdf") {sDesc = "Temporary Safety Fence"}
  else if (files==="015639.pdf") {sDesc = "Tree Protection and Trimming"}
  else if (files==="01570.pdf") {sDesc = "Temporary Controls"}
  else if (files==="015700.pdf") {sDesc = "Temporary Controls"}
  else if (files==="015710.pdf") {sDesc = "Storm Water Pollution Prevention"}
  else if (files==="015713.pdf") {sDesc = "Erosion Sedimentation Control"}
  else if (files==="015719.pdf") {sDesc = "Temporary Environmental Controls"}
  else if (files==="015720.pdf") {sDesc = "Environmental Controls"}
  else if (files==="015721.pdf") {sDesc = "Indoor Air Quality Controls"}
  else if (files==="015730.pdf") {sDesc = "Water Pollution Control"}
  else if (files==="015750.pdf") {sDesc = "Tree and Plant Protection"}
  else if (files==="015760.pdf") {sDesc = "Protected Species"}
  else if (files==="01580.pdf") {sDesc = "Project Identification"}
  else if (files==="015800.pdf") {sDesc = "Project Identification"}
  else if (files==="015813.pdf") {sDesc = "Temporary Project Signage"}
  else if (files==="01590.pdf") {sDesc = "Field Offices and Sheds"}
  else if (files==="01600.pdf") {sDesc = "Product Requirements"}
  else if (files==="016000.pdf") {sDesc = "Product Requirements"}
  else if (files==="016000.02.pdf") {sDesc = "Agreement for Storing Materials and Equipment Off Site"}
  else if (files==="01601.pdf") {sDesc = "Job Conditions"}
  else if (files==="01610.pdf") {sDesc = "Basic Product Requirements"}
  else if (files==="016100.pdf") {sDesc = "Common Product Requirements"}
  else if (files==="016110.pdf") {sDesc = "Project Identification"}
  else if (files==="01620.pdf") {sDesc = "Product Options"}
  else if (files==="016200.pdf") {sDesc = "Substitutions"}
  else if (files==="01630.pdf") {sDesc = "Product Substitution Procedures"}
  else if (files==="016300.pdf") {sDesc = "Product Substitutions"}
  else if (files==="01635.pdf") {sDesc = "Substitution Procedures"}
  else if (files==="01640.pdf") {sDesc = "Owner-Furnished Products"}
  else if (files==="016400.pdf") {sDesc = "Owner Furnished Products"}
  else if (files==="016440.pdf") {sDesc = "Government Furnished Products"}
  else if (files==="01650.pdf") {sDesc = "Product Delivery Requirements"}
  else if (files==="01660.pdf") {sDesc = "Product Storage and Handling Requirements"}
  else if (files==="016600.pdf") {sDesc = "Product Delivery and Storage Handling Requirements"}
  else if (files==="01700.pdf") {sDesc = "Execution Requirements"}
  else if (files==="017000.pdf") {sDesc = "Execution Requirements"}
  else if (files==="01710.pdf") {sDesc = "Examination"}
  else if (files==="017100.pdf") {sDesc = "Examination and Preparation"}
  else if (files==="017120.pdf") {sDesc = "Surveying"}
  else if (files==="01720.pdf") {sDesc = "Preparation"}
  else if (files==="017200.pdf") {sDesc = "Field Engineering"}
  else if (files==="01730.pdf") {sDesc = "Execution"}
  else if (files==="017300.pdf") {sDesc = "Execution"}
  else if (files==="01731.pdf") {sDesc = "Cutting and Patching"}
  else if (files==="017310.pdf") {sDesc = "Cutting and Patching"}
  else if (files==="01732.pdf") {sDesc = "Waste Management"}
  else if (files==="017329.pdf") {sDesc = "Cutting and Patching"}
  else if (files==="01740.pdf") {sDesc = "Cleaning"}
  else if (files==="017400.pdf") {sDesc = "Warranties"}
  else if (files==="017410.pdf") {sDesc = "Construction Waste Management"}
  else if (files==="017419.pdf") {sDesc = "Construction Waste Management and Disposal"}
  else if (files==="017420.pdf") {sDesc = "Construction Demolition Waste Management and Disposal"}
  else if (files==="017423.pdf") {sDesc = "Cleaning"}
  else if (files==="01743.pdf") {sDesc = "Hazardous Universal Waste Management and Disposal"}
  else if (files==="01750.pdf") {sDesc = "Starting and Adjusting"}
  else if (files==="017513.pdf") {sDesc = "Checkout Procedures"}
  else if (files==="01760.pdf") {sDesc = "Protecting Installed Construction"}
  else if (files==="01770.pdf") {sDesc = "Closeout Procedures"}
  else if (files==="017700.pdf") {sDesc = "Closeout Procedures"}
  else if (files==="017710.pdf") {sDesc = "Warranties and Bonds"}
  else if (files==="017720.pdf") {sDesc = "Project Closeout"}
  else if (files==="017721.pdf") {sDesc = "No Asbestos Affidavit"}
  else if (files==="017722.pdf") {sDesc = "No Lead Affidavit"}
  else if (files==="01780.pdf") {sDesc = "Closeout Submittals"}
  else if (files==="017800.pdf") {sDesc = "Closeout Submittals"}
  else if (files==="017810.pdf") {sDesc = "Warranties Forms"}
  else if (files==="01781.pdf") {sDesc = "Project Record Documents"}
  else if (files==="017810.pdf") {sDesc = "Project Record Documents"}
  else if (files==="017813.pdf") {sDesc = "Bonds and Warranties"}
  else if (files==="01782.pdf") {sDesc = "Operation and Maintenance Data"}
  else if (files==="017820.pdf") {sDesc = "Operation and Maintenance Data"}
  else if (files==="017823.pdf") {sDesc = "Operation and Maintenance Data"}
  else if (files==="017830.pdf") {sDesc = "Demonstration and Training"}
  else if (files==="017839.pdf") {sDesc = "Project Record Documents"}
  else if (files==="017843.pdf") {sDesc = "Spare Parts"}
  else if (files==="017846.pdf") {sDesc = "Extra Stock Materials"}
  else if (files==="017900.pdf") {sDesc = "Demonstration and Training"}
  else if (files==="017920.pdf") {sDesc = "Training"}
  else if (files==="01800.pdf") {sDesc = "Facility Operation"}
  else if (files==="01810.pdf") {sDesc = "Commissioning"}
  else if (files==="01811.pdf") {sDesc = "Sustainable Design Requirements"}
  else if (files==="018111.pdf") {sDesc = "Sustainable Design Requirements"}
  else if (files==="018113.pdf") {sDesc = "Sustainable Design Requirements"}
  else if (files==="018113.13.pdf") {sDesc = "Sustainable Design Requirements"}
  else if (files==="018113.23.pdf") {sDesc = "Sustainable Design Requirements"}
  else if (files==="018115.pdf") {sDesc = "Construction Indoor Air Quality Management"}
  else if (files==="01820.pdf") {sDesc = "Demonstration and Training"}
  else if (files==="01830.pdf") {sDesc = "Operation and Maintenance"}
  else if (files==="01890.pdf") {sDesc = "Reconstruction"}
  else if (files==="01900.pdf") {sDesc = "Facility Decommissioning"}
  else if (files==="019000.pdf") {sDesc = "General Commissioning Requirements"}
  else if (files==="019100.pdf") {sDesc = "General Commissioning Requirements"}
  else if (files==="019113.pdf") {sDesc = "Commissioning"}
  else if (files==="019114.pdf") {sDesc = "Commissioning Authority Responsibilities"}
  else if (files==="02001.pdf") {sDesc = "Mobilization"}
  else if (files==="02005.pdf") {sDesc = "Excavation"}
  else if (files==="02010.pdf") {sDesc = "Subsurface Soils Investigation"}
  else if (files==="02234.pdf") {sDesc = "Sub Base Course"}
  else if (files==="02235.pdf") {sDesc = "Crushed Base Course"}
  else if (files==="02237.pdf") {sDesc = "Site Clearing"}
  else if (files==="02240.pdf") {sDesc = "Dewatering"}
  else if (files==="02246.pdf") {sDesc = "Topsoiling and Finished Grading"}
  else if (files==="02250.pdf") {sDesc = "Shoring and Underpinning"}
  else if (files==="02251.pdf") {sDesc = "Shoring"}
  else if (files==="02260.pdf") {sDesc = "Excavation Support and Protection"}
  else if (files==="02270.pdf") {sDesc = "Slope Protections and Erosion Control"}
  else if (files==="02275.pdf") {sDesc = "Rip Rap"}
  else if (files==="02280.pdf") {sDesc = "Grade Adjustment and Abandonment of Existing Miscellaneous Structures"}
  else if (files==="02285.pdf") {sDesc = "Rebuilt Miscellaneous Structure"}
  else if (files==="02290.pdf") {sDesc = "Site Monitoring"}
  else if (files==="02300.pdf") {sDesc = "Earthwork"}
  else if (files==="023000.pdf") {sDesc = "Subsurface Investigation"}
  else if (files==="02301.pdf") {sDesc = "Buried Steel Pipe and Fittings"}
  else if (files==="02302.pdf") {sDesc = "Buried Ductile Iron Pipe and Fittings"}
  else if (files==="02303.pdf") {sDesc = "Buried PVC Pipe with Ductile Iron Fittings"}
  else if (files==="02304.pdf") {sDesc = "Fusible PVC Pipe with Ductile Iron Fittings"}
  else if (files==="02310.pdf") {sDesc = "Grading"}
  else if (files==="02315.pdf") {sDesc = "Excavation and Fill"}
  else if (files==="02320.pdf") {sDesc = "Pipe Bedding and Backfill"}
  else if (files==="023200.pdf") {sDesc = "Geotechnical Investigation Report"}
  else if (files==="02321.pdf") {sDesc = "Casing Pipe"}
  else if (files==="02325.pdf") {sDesc = "Dredging"}
  else if (files==="02330.pdf") {sDesc = "Embankment"}
  else if (files==="02335.pdf") {sDesc = "Subgrade and Roadbed"}
  else if (files==="02340.pdf") {sDesc = "Soil Stabilization"}
  else if (files==="02350.pdf") {sDesc = "Reference Markers"}
  else if (files==="02360.pdf") {sDesc = "Soil Treatment"}
  else if (files==="02370.pdf") {sDesc = "Erosion and Sedimentation Control"}
  else if (files==="02380.pdf") {sDesc = "Scour Protection"}
  else if (files==="02390.pdf") {sDesc = "Shoreline Protection & Mooring Structure"}
  else if (files==="02400.pdf") {sDesc = "Tunneling Boring and Jacking"}
  else if (files==="024000.pdf") {sDesc = "Demolition"}
  else if (files==="02410.pdf") {sDesc = "Tunnel Excavation"}
  else if (files==="024100.pdf") {sDesc = "Building Demolition"}
  else if (files==="024101.pdf") {sDesc = "Cutting and Patching"}
  else if (files==="024102.pdf") {sDesc = "Selective Demolition"}
  else if (files==="024116.pdf") {sDesc = "Structure Demolition"}
  else if (files==="024119.pdf") {sDesc = "Selective Structure Demolition"}
  else if (files==="024121.pdf") {sDesc = "Removal of Existing Equipment"}
  else if (files==="024120.pdf") {sDesc = "Building Demolition"}
  else if (files==="02420.pdf") {sDesc = "Initial Tunnel Support System"}
  else if (files==="02425.pdf") {sDesc = "Tunnel Lining"}
  else if (files==="02430.pdf") {sDesc = "Tunnel Grouting"}
  else if (files==="024300.pdf") {sDesc = "Removal and Disposal of Structures and Obstructions"}
  else if (files==="02440.pdf") {sDesc = "Immersed and Sunken Tube Tunnel"}
  else if (files==="02441.pdf") {sDesc = "Microtunneling"}
  else if (files==="02442.pdf") {sDesc = "Cut and Cover Tunnel"}
  else if (files==="02443.pdf") {sDesc = "Tunnel Leak Repair"}
  else if (files==="02444.pdf") {sDesc = "Shaft Construction"}
  else if (files==="02445.pdf") {sDesc = "Boring or Jacking Conduit"}
  else if (files==="02446.pdf") {sDesc = "Electrical Raceway Horizontal Bores"}
  else if (files==="02450.pdf") {sDesc = "Foundation & Load-Bearing Element"}
  else if (files==="02455.pdf") {sDesc = "Driven Pile"}
  else if (files==="024600.pdf") {sDesc = "Steel Helical Pulldown Piers"}
  else if (files==="02465.pdf") {sDesc = "Bored Pile"}
  else if (files==="02475.pdf") {sDesc = "Caisson"}
  else if (files==="02480.pdf") {sDesc = "Foundation Wall"}
  else if (files==="02490.pdf") {sDesc = "Anchor"}
  else if (files==="02495.pdf") {sDesc = "Instrumentation and Monitoring"}
  else if (files==="02500.pdf") {sDesc = "Utility Service"}
  else if (files==="02505.pdf") {sDesc = "Construction Seal"}
  else if (files==="02510.pdf") {sDesc = "Water Distribution"}
  else if (files==="025100.pdf") {sDesc = "Radon Mitigation System"}
  else if (files==="02511.pdf") {sDesc = "Concrete Paving"}
  else if (files==="02515.pdf") {sDesc = "Portland Cement Concrete Pavement"}
  else if (files==="02520.pdf") {sDesc = "Well"}
  else if (files==="02528.pdf") {sDesc = "Concrete Curb and Gutter"}
  else if (files==="02529.pdf") {sDesc = "Concrete Sidewalks Driveways Approaches Curb Turn Fillets"}
  else if (files==="02530.pdf") {sDesc = "Sanitary Sewerage"}
  else if (files==="025300.pdf") {sDesc = "Sanitary Sewerage"}
  else if (files==="02553.pdf") {sDesc = "Natural Gas Distribution"}
  else if (files==="02540.pdf") {sDesc = "Septic Tank System"}
  else if (files==="02546.pdf") {sDesc = "Aggregate Surfacing"}
  else if (files==="02550.pdf") {sDesc = "Piped Energy Distribution"}
  else if (files==="025530.pdf") {sDesc = "Natural Gas Distribution"}
  else if (files==="02570.pdf") {sDesc = "Process Materials Distribution Structure"}
  else if (files==="02580.pdf") {sDesc = "Electrical & Communication Structure"}
  else if (files==="02581.pdf") {sDesc = "Pavement Marking and Markers"}
  else if (files==="02590.pdf") {sDesc = "Site Grounding"}
  else if (files==="02600.pdf") {sDesc = "Drainage and Containment"}
  else if (files==="02603.pdf") {sDesc = "Casing"}
  else if (files==="02605.pdf") {sDesc = "Dampproofing"}
  else if (files==="02607.pdf") {sDesc = "Precast Concrete Pipe Structures Manholes and Covers"}
  else if (files==="02610.pdf") {sDesc = "Pipe Culvert"}
  else if (files==="02611.pdf") {sDesc = "High Density Polytheylene Pipe"}
  else if (files==="02616.pdf") {sDesc = "Pavement Removal and Repair"}
  else if (files==="02620.pdf") {sDesc = "Subdrainage"}
  else if (files==="026225.pdf") {sDesc = "Excavation and Removal of Contaminated Materials"}
  else if (files==="02630.pdf") {sDesc = "Storm Drainage"}
  else if (files==="02640.pdf") {sDesc = "Culverts & Manufactured Construction"}
  else if (files==="02650.pdf") {sDesc = "Concrete Paving Joint Sealants"}
  else if (files==="02660.pdf") {sDesc = "Ponds and Reservoir"}
  else if (files==="02667.pdf") {sDesc = "Water Lines"}
  else if (files==="02668.pdf") {sDesc = "WAter Service Connections"}
  else if (files==="02669.pdf") {sDesc = "Water Line Accessories"}
  else if (files==="02670.pdf") {sDesc = "Constructed Wetland"}
  else if (files==="02671.pdf") {sDesc = "Trace and Reference Markers"}
  else if (files==="02675.pdf") {sDesc = "Disinfection of Water System"}
  else if (files==="02676.pdf") {sDesc = "Disinfection of Water Storage Facilities"}
  else if (files==="02677.pdf") {sDesc = "Cleaning and Disinfection of Water Distribution Systems"}
  else if (files==="02700.pdf") {sDesc = "Bases  Ballasts  Pavements and Appurtenance"}
  else if (files==="02704.pdf") {sDesc = "Multi Port Effluent Diffuser System"}
 else if (files==="02990.pdf") {sDesc = "Structure Moving"}
  else if (files==="03002.pdf") {sDesc = "Concrete"}
  else if (files==="030100.pdf") {sDesc = "Maintenance of Concrete"}
  else if (files==="03050.pdf") {sDesc = "Basic Concrete Materials and Methods"}
  else if (files==="03051.pdf") {sDesc = "Cold Weather Concreting"}
  else if (files==="03052.pdf") {sDesc = "Hot Weather Concreting"}
  else if (files==="03100.pdf") {sDesc = "Concrete Forms and Accessories"}
  else if (files==="031000.pdf") {sDesc = "Concrete Forming and Accessories"}
  else if (files==="03110.pdf") {sDesc = "Structural Cast-in-Place Concrete Form"}
  else if (files==="031100.pdf") {sDesc = "Permanent Forms"}
  else if (files==="031110.pdf") {sDesc = "Concrete Forming"}
  else if (files==="031113.pdf") {sDesc = "Structural Cast in Place Concrete Forming"}
  else if (files==="03119.pdf") {sDesc = "Insulating Concrete Forming"}
  else if (files==="03120.pdf") {sDesc = "Architectural Cast-in-Place Concrete Form"}
  else if (files==="03130.pdf") {sDesc = "Permanent Form"}
  else if (files==="03150.pdf") {sDesc = "Concrete Accessories"}
  else if (files==="031511.pdf") {sDesc = "Concrete Anchors and Inserts"}
  else if (files==="03200.pdf") {sDesc = "Concrete Reinforcement"}
  else if (files==="032000.pdf") {sDesc = "Concrete Reinforcing"}
  else if (files==="03210.pdf") {sDesc = "Reinforcing Steel"}
  else if (files==="032100.pdf") {sDesc = "Reinforcement Bars"}
  else if (files==="03220.pdf") {sDesc = "Welded Wire Fabric"}
  else if (files==="03230.pdf") {sDesc = "Stressing Tendon"}
  else if (files==="03240.pdf") {sDesc = "Fibrous Reinforcing"}
  else if (files==="03250.pdf") {sDesc = "Post-Tensioning"}
  else if (files==="03300.pdf") {sDesc = "Cast-in-Place Concrete"}
  else if (files==="03301.pdf") {sDesc = "Cast in Place Concrete"}
  else if (files==="033000.pdf") {sDesc = "Cast-In-Place Concrete"}
  else if (files==="033010.pdf") {sDesc = "Concrete Testing and Inspection Service"}
  else if (files==="033020.pdf") {sDesc = "Post Installed Anchors"}
  else if (files==="033030.pdf") {sDesc = "Cast In Place Concrete Slabs"}
  else if (files==="033053.pdf") {sDesc = "Misc Cast In Place Concrete"}
  else if (files==="03310.pdf") {sDesc = "Structural Concrete"}
  else if (files==="033111.pdf") {sDesc = "Norma Weight Structural Concrete"}
  else if (files==="03315.pdf") {sDesc = "Site Conrete Sidewalks and Slabs"}
  else if (files==="033200.pdf") {sDesc = "Elevated Composite Concrete Slabs"}
  else if (files==="033300.pdf") {sDesc = "CAst in Place Architectural Concrete"}
  else if (files==="03330.pdf") {sDesc = "Architectural Concrete"}
  else if (files==="03340.pdf") {sDesc = "Low Density Concrete"}
  else if (files==="03350.pdf") {sDesc = "Concrete Finishing"}
  else if (files==="033500.pdf") {sDesc = "Concrete Finishing"}
  else if (files==="03351.pdf") {sDesc = "Concrete Floor Finishes"}
  else if (files==="033511.pdf") {sDesc = "Concrete Floor Finishes"}
  else if (files==="033513.pdf") {sDesc = "Concrete Floor Finishing"}
  else if (files==="033517.pdf") {sDesc = "Concrete Sealer Hardener Waterproofer"}
  else if (files==="033533.pdf") {sDesc = "Stamped Concrete Finishing"}
  else if (files==="0335400.pdf") {sDesc = "Cast Underlayment"}
  else if (files==="03360.pdf") {sDesc = "Concrete Finishes"}
  else if (files==="033600.pdf") {sDesc = "Special Concrete Floor Finish"}
  else if (files==="033650.pdf") {sDesc = "Concrete Floor Dye"}
  else if (files==="03370.pdf") {sDesc = "Specially Placed Concrete"}
  else if (files==="03380.pdf") {sDesc = "Post-Tensioned Concrete"}
  else if (files==="03390.pdf") {sDesc = "Concrete Curing"}
  else if (files==="033923.pdf") {sDesc = "Membrane Concrete Curing"}
  else if (files==="033950.pdf") {sDesc = "Sealer Hardener Concrete Floor Finish"}
  else if (files==="03400.pdf") {sDesc = "Precast Concrete"}
  else if (files==="03409.pdf") {sDesc = "Precast Concrete Septic Tanks"}
  else if (files==="03410.pdf") {sDesc = "Plant-Precast Structural Concrete"}
  else if (files==="034100.pdf") {sDesc = "Precast Structural Concrete"}
  else if (files==="03420.pdf") {sDesc = "Plant-Precast Structural Post-Tensioned Concrete"}
  else if (files==="03430.pdf") {sDesc = "Site-Precast Structural Concrete"}
  else if (files==="03440.pdf") {sDesc = "Precast Concrete Manholes"}
  else if (files==="03450.pdf") {sDesc = "Plant-Precast Architectural Concrete"}
  else if (files==="034500.pdf") {sDesc = "Precast Architectural Wall Panels"}
  else if (files==="03451.pdf") {sDesc = "Architectural Precast Concrete"}
  else if (files==="03460.pdf") {sDesc = "Site-Precast Architectural Concrete"}
  else if (files==="03470.pdf") {sDesc = "Tilt-Up Precast Concrete"}
  else if (files==="03480.pdf") {sDesc = "Precast Concrete Specialties"}
  else if (files==="034800.pdf") {sDesc = "Precast Concrete Specialties"}
  else if (files==="03490.pdf") {sDesc = "Glass-Fiber-Reinforced Precast Concrete"}
  else if (files==="03500.pdf") {sDesc = "Cementitious Decks and Underlayment"}
  else if (files==="03510.pdf") {sDesc = "Cementitious Roof Deck"}
  else if (files==="03520.pdf") {sDesc = "Lightweight Concrete Roof Insulation"}
  else if (files==="03530.pdf") {sDesc = "Concrete Topping"}
  else if (files==="035300.pdf") {sDesc = "Concrete Topping"}
  else if (files==="03540.pdf") {sDesc = "Cementitious Underlayment"}
  else if (files==="035400.pdf") {sDesc = "Cementitious Underlayment"}
  else if (files==="035413.pdf") {sDesc = "Gypsum Cement Underlayment"}
  else if (files==="035416.pdf") {sDesc = "Gypsum Cement Underlayment"}
  else if (files==="033562.pdf") {sDesc = "Ground Concrete Floor Finish"}
  else if (files==="034116.pdf") {sDesc = "Precast Structural Concrete"}
  else if (files==="03600.pdf") {sDesc = "Grout"}
  else if (files==="036100.pdf") {sDesc = "Non Metallic Grout"}
  else if (files==="036220.pdf") {sDesc = "Non Shrink Grout"}
  else if (files==="03700.pdf") {sDesc = "Mass Concrete"}
  else if (files==="038110.pdf") {sDesc = "Concrete Removal"}
  else if (files==="03900.pdf") {sDesc = "Concrete Restoration and Cleaning"}
  else if (files==="03910.pdf") {sDesc = "Concrete Cleaning"}
  else if (files==="03920.pdf") {sDesc = "Concrete Resurfacing"}
  else if (files==="03930.pdf") {sDesc = "Concrete Rehabilitation"}
  else if (files==="040110.pdf") {sDesc = "Unit Masonry Cleaning"}
  else if (files==="040110.71.pdf") {sDesc = "Dumbwaiter Rehabilitation"}
  else if (files==="040120.63.pdf") {sDesc = "Brick Masonry Repair"}
  else if (files==="040120.71.pdf") {sDesc = "Elevator Rehabilitation"}
  else if (files==="040130.71.pdf") {sDesc = "Escalators and Moving Walks Rehabilitation"}
  else if (files==="040140.pdf") {sDesc = "Maintenance of Stone Assemblies"}
  else if (files==="040140.71.pdf") {sDesc = "Lifts Rehabilitation"}
  else if (files==="04050.pdf") {sDesc = "Basic Masonry Materials and Methods"}
  else if (files==="040503.pdf") {sDesc = "Masonry Mortaring and Grouting"}
  else if (files==="040513.pdf") {sDesc = "Cement nad Lime Masonry Mortaring"}
  else if (files==="040516.pdf") {sDesc = "Masonry Grouting"}
  else if (files==="040521.pdf") {sDesc = "Masonry Veneer Ties"}
  else if (files==="040523.pdf") {sDesc = "Masonry Accessories"}
  else if (files==="04060.pdf") {sDesc = "Masonry Mortar"}
  else if (files==="04070.pdf") {sDesc = "Masonry Grout"}
  else if (files==="04080.pdf") {sDesc = "Masonry Anchorage and Reinforcement"}
  else if (files==="04090.pdf") {sDesc = "Masonry Accessories"}
  else if (files==="04200.pdf") {sDesc = "Masonry Unit"}
  else if (files==="042000.pdf") {sDesc = "Unit Masonry"}
  else if (files==="042001.pdf") {sDesc = "Masonry Veneer"}
  else if (files==="042002.pdf") {sDesc = "Single Wythe Unit Masonry"}
  else if (files==="042010.pdf") {sDesc = "Reinforced Unit Masonry"}
  else if (files==="042019.pdf") {sDesc = "Veneer Unit Masonry"}
  else if (files==="04210.pdf") {sDesc = "Clay Masonry Unit"}
  else if (files==="042113.pdf") {sDesc = "Brick Masonry"}
  else if (files==="04220.pdf") {sDesc = "Concrete Masonry Unit"}
  else if (files==="042200.pdf") {sDesc = "Concrete Masonry Units"}
  else if (files==="042210.pdf") {sDesc = "Masonry Testing and Inspection Services"}
  else if (files==="04230.pdf") {sDesc = "Calcium Silicate Units Masonry"}
  else if (files==="042300.pdf") {sDesc = "Glass Unit Masonry"}
  else if (files==="042400.pdf") {sDesc = "Anchored Brick Veneer Units"}
  else if (files==="042613.pdf") {sDesc = "Masonry Veneer"}
  else if (files==="042616.pdf") {sDesc = "Adhered Masonry Veneer"}
  else if (files==="04270.pdf") {sDesc = "Glass Masonry Unit"}
  else if (files==="042731.pdf") {sDesc = "Reinforced Unit Masonry"}
  else if (files==="04290.pdf") {sDesc = "Adobe Masonry Unit"}
  else if (files==="04400.pdf") {sDesc = "Stone"}
  else if (files==="04410.pdf") {sDesc = "Stone Materials"}
  else if (files==="04420.pdf") {sDesc = "Collected Stone"}
  else if (files==="04430.pdf") {sDesc = "Quarried Stone"}
  else if (files==="044300.pdf") {sDesc = "Stone Masonry"}
  else if (files==="044301.pdf") {sDesc = "Stone Masonry Veneer"}
  else if (files==="044313.13.pdf") {sDesc = "Anchored Stone Masonry Veneer"}
  else if (files==="04500.pdf") {sDesc = "Refractories"}
  else if (files==="04550.pdf") {sDesc = "Flue Liner"}
  else if (files==="04560.pdf") {sDesc = "Combustion Chamber"}
  else if (files==="04570.pdf") {sDesc = "Castable Refractories"}
  else if (files==="04580.pdf") {sDesc = "Refractory Brick"}
  else if (files==="04600.pdf") {sDesc = "Corrosion-Resistant Masonry"}
  else if (files==="04610.pdf") {sDesc = "Chemical-Resistant Brick"}
  else if (files==="04620.pdf") {sDesc = "Vitrified Clay Liner Plate"}
  else if (files==="04700.pdf") {sDesc = "Simulted Masonry"}
  else if (files==="047000.pdf") {sDesc = "Manufactured Stone"}
  else if (files==="04710.pdf") {sDesc = "Simulated Brick"}
  else if (files==="04720.pdf") {sDesc = "Cast Stone"}
  else if (files==="047200.pdf") {sDesc = "Cast Stone Masonry"}
  else if (files==="04730.pdf") {sDesc = "Simulated Stone"}
  else if (files==="047300.pdf") {sDesc = "Simulated Stone"}
  else if (files==="04800.pdf") {sDesc = "Masonry Assemblies"}
  else if (files==="04810.pdf") {sDesc = "Unit Masonry Assemblies"}
  else if (files==="048100.pdf") {sDesc = "Unit Masonry Precast Conc Sill"}

   else {sDesc = ""}
console.log(files + sDesc);
}
%>
```

Comment: Do you have a database available to store this lookup data? It isn’t scalable or a good practice to have a static cache in memory of all these strings. If performance is a huge factor, then you could use a really fast (and free) key-value store like Redis.

Comment: Ok. I will look into this. I think you are probably right. Way too many strings in the cache. I have worked with mongo a little bit but never redis.

Comment: You could use Mongo too. With a key-value store like Redis, this use case is very straightforward since the key will be the filename and the value would be your **sDesc** matching string value.

Comment: I like the idea of redis. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd consider looking at a database for this sort of data. However if you decide not to, we can still do this fairly easily. You'll want to construct a "mapping object" which stores the data, and then look through that rather than creating a giant if statement series. Here is an incredibly simple example with a little bit of data, this approach uses an array and a for each loop to look up the data.

```
var mapper = [
  {
    fileName: '000001.pdf',
    description: 'Title Page'
  },
  {
    fileName: '00001.pdf',
    description: 'Project Title Page'
  },
  {
    fileName: '00350.pdf',
    description: 'Project Financial Information'
  }
];

function processFile(file) {
  var sDesc = '';

  // This really is not the most efficient way, but it is the simplest
  // to understand. Really you probably want to use the .find function
  // here instead. Or any other optimisation.
  mapper.forEach(function(mapping) {
    if (file.name === mapping.fileName) {
      sDesc = description;
    }
  });

  return sDesc;
}
```

In this case we store all the data (mapping from a file name to a description) in an array. Then when we process a file, we loop through that array to find the information we want and then can act from there. You can then use this `processFile` function in something else. For example, you may wish to process multiple files, so using the above we could then do this.

```
function processAllFiles(fileCollection) {
  // Again here, we would probably use a map function but
  // for simplicity lets go with a simple to understand loop.
  fileCollection.forEach(function(file) {
    var fileDescription = processFile(file);

    // Do something with this fileDescription...
  });
}
```

There are many other ways you could do this as well which make it even easier. The first would be to use a database, where you can tell the database "find me the description for file name X" and it pulls it straight out for you. This is ideal if your data is going to grow over time or is large to begin with.

Comment: Thanks Elliot. These are very good suggestions. I am currently lea bing towards a DB but I might play around with a “mapping object” for fun and see how it performs. It is a large amount of data so Redis hash data types might be a better solution. Thanks for the thoughtful examples and response.

Comment: If it's long term data you'll want to use something other than redis probably. Redis is great as a cache for temporary storage or data that doesn't matter. If the data is going to be kept around for a long time then checkout something that stores the data on disk.

Comment: Also if this answer is correct to the question you asked, could you please mark it so? :)

Comment: Mongo? Is the other dB i have a little experience with then.

Comment: Thanks again Elliot!

Comment: Mongo is a fine choice, redis is really really great but it holds everything in memory. So if it crashes all your data is gone. Mongo, Postgres, MySQL, CouchDB, all those sorts of things save the data to the disk so they're all good choices if this data is going to live for a while.

Comment: Note: Redis can save data too (and replicate across a master-slave cluster) so it isn’t accurate that you must lose data between reboots.

Comment: @SylonZero this is completely true, it's just traditionally not used for long term storage. I'll leave my comment there so the chain makes sense for the future but yes I didn't mention that important bit of info, thanks.